# how to make a program to be invoked by #!/bin/foo at the top of a script?

Tags: bash, shell

As you know shell scripts have a "#!/bin/bash" at the top of script which ends the  script to shell binary and then shell will runs that . I want to make a program which should be called like "#!/bin/foo" then it should read script . but I do'nt know how should I do sth like this . could sb help ?

Comment: The purpose of `#!/bin/bash` at the top of a script is to tell the shell what interpreter to use for the rest of the script. This line can optionally accept parameters. Could you make more clear with an example what it is you want to do? And why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: I want to create a c program to act as new interpreter for shell to be used for a new type of script . but I do'nt know how to make my program act as a interpreter !

Comment: @alireza7991 then you need to create a program. this is not what you are asking in your question.

Comment: btw, I also used to wonder how to make one's custom program associate with file extensions.

Comment: @alireza7991 I don't think there's anything special you have to do for your C program for `bash` to honor it when it sees its path in the shebang line. Write your interpreter as you would normally, put it into a path, and call it out on the `#!/my/path/myshell` line. `bash` isn't looking inside the interpreter to figure anything out special to do this.

Comment: I can't find where this is documented, but the interpreter program in the shebang line *cannot* be an interpreted script, it must be a compiled executable.

Comment: @glennjackman not sure which OS you're referring to, but it works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `#!/bin/foo` shebang is run, `/bin/foo` is run, with the filename as an argument, e.g. if the filename is `bar`, then the command line that would be run is `/bin/foo bar`. To implement it in C, check whether `main()`'s `argc` (argument count) is `1`, then the only element of `argv` will be the filename so you can use `argv[0]` to access the filename. From there I guess you would want to `fopen()` the file, `fread()` it, and do what you want with it.

Comment: @alireza7991 please accept the best answer (click the tick button next to the best answer)

Answer (score 1):

1. write an empty script starting with `#!/bin/echo` (and execute it) to see what arguments the shell will pass to your program
2. write a C program that handles those arguments when passed to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you prefer. For instance If I create a text file called `test`:

```
#!/bin/cat
content
```

And I give the text file write permissions with `chmod`:

```
chmod +x test
```

Now, I can execute it and the result is invoking cat printing the file contents:

```
$ ./test
#!/bin/cat
content
$
```

Comment: You didn't understand his question correctly. He/she wants to create his own program which can be used in a shebang.

Comment: @RamchandraApte I understood the problem. cat is an example, he can use whatever he wants...

Comment: See his comment on his question, "I want to create a c program to act as new interpreter for shell to be used for a new type of script . but I do'nt know how to make my program act as a interpreter ! ".